# Expose secondary currency to WooCommerce REST API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

Im using WPML with WooCommerce Multilingual to a secondary currency in the Multi-currency setup to display different currencies per language. This works well - except that I cant get the secondary price to show in  the WooCommerce REST API when using GET.

The prices is set per varation - and I get this repsonse:

```
"lang": "en",
  "multi-currency-prices": {
    "EURO": {
      "regular_price": 0
    }
```

Why do I get a 0 in price, and is it possible to expose the secondary price to the API?

Comment: How are you fetching the price?

Comment: @montrealist Im using a basic GET call: https://domain.local/wp-json/wc/v3/products/162031